# „Anpassung an den/die aktuell herrschenden Anforderungen“?

Tags: preposition

Ich habe kein gutes Gefühl bei diesem Satz:

> Meistens handelt es sich vielmehr um die Konfiguration und Anpassung
>   der Serverleistung an den aktuell herrschenden Anforderungen.

Es hört sich für mich besser an, wenn ich sage: *an die aktuell herrschende Anforderungen*, aber MS Word sagt mir, das sei falsch ...

Was ist nun richtig und was ist die Regel, die man hier anwenden soll?

Comment: Die Regel ist _automatische Grammatikprüfung ignorieren, im Wörterbuch nachschauen_: http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=Anpassung&l=deen&lf=de _Anpassung an_ mit Akkusativ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word kommt bei der Grammatikprüfung durcheinander, weil der Satz ein wenig kompliziert gebaut ist. Der Satz ist die Verschmelzung zweier Sätze:

> 1: *Meistens handelt es sich vielmehr um die Konfiguration der Serverleistung.*
>   <sub>Oder aufs Wesentliche reduziert:</sub>
>   1a: *Es handelt es um die Konfiguration der Serverleistung.*
>
> 2: *Meistens handelt es sich vielmehr um die Anpassung der Serverleistung an die aktuell herrschenden Anforderungen.*
>   <sub>gekürzt:</sub>
>   2a: *Es handelt es um die Anpassung der Serverleistung an die Anforderungen.*

In 1a kommt die Konfiguration mit nur einem Objekt aus, das im Genitiv steht:

> Die Konfiguration *wessen*? - Die Konfiguration *der Serverleistung*.

In 2a hat die Anpassung zusätzlich zum Genitivobjekt noch ein zweites (optionales) Objekt, das auf die Präposition »an« folgt und, weil es sich um ein Ziel handelt, im Akkusativ steht.

> Die Anpassung *wessen* an *wen/was*? - Die Anpassung *der Serverleistung* an ***die*** Anforderungen.

Also:

Das fragliche Wort muss der Artikel »die« sein, weil das der bestimmte Plural-Artikel im Akkusativ ist.

Der Akkusativ wiederum ist erforderlich, weil in der Anpassung *an* etwas dieses *etwas* ein Ziel ist, und weil ein Ziel, das auf »*an*« folgt, im Akkusativ stehen muss.

Die *Anforderungen* wiederum sind ein Objekt, das ganz allein zur Anpassung, nicht aber zur Konfiguration gehört.

Dadurch, dass die Konfiguration und die Anpassung zu einer Aufzählung zusammengefasst sind, und weil beide Begriffe ein identisches Genitivobjekt besitzen, ist es gestattet, dieses Objekt nur einmal im Satz zu verwenden. Insofern ist der Beispielsatz eigentlich eine Verkürzung dieses Satzes (doppelte Satzteile sind fett hervorgehoben):

> Meistens handelt es sich vielmehr **um die** Konfiguration **der Serverleistung** und **um die** Anpassung **der Serverleistung** an die aktuell herrschenden Anforderungen.

Die Grammatikprüfung wird vermutlich daran gescheitert sein, diesen Satz korrekt zu analysieren.

Comment: Wahnsinn. Vielen Dank dafür!